# Query join tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables:

**Medaltypes**

```
id          name           description
6           Medalname      Right on!
7           Medalname2     Aswsome
8           Medalname3     Allright
```

**Medals**

```
id          medaltype      userref   
1           6              MYUSERNAME
2           7              MYUSERNAME
3           6              OTHERUSER
4           6              OTHERUSERALSO
```

**Userprofiles**

```
userid       userref 
1            MYUSERNAME
2            OTHERUSER
3            OTHERUSERALSO
```

What I want is a result of all medaltypes for a specific userid including the onces earned and the onces still to be earned. Like for userid 1 this would be as outcome:

```
Medalname        - Earned
Medalname2       - Earned
Medalname3       - To be earned
```

I can get a list with the Medaltypes and Medals with a left join but as soon as I join in (let alone query on specific userid) Userprofiles it reduces the list.

How should this query look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `LEFT JOIN`, but the condition on the user needs to go in the `ON` clause:

```
select ml.name,
       (case when m.id is not null then 'EARNED' else 'TO BE EARNED'
        end)
from medaltypes ml left join
     medals m
     on m.medaltype = ml.id and
        m.userref = 'MYUSERNAME';
```

Your data structure is awkward.  `Medals` should not contain `userref`; it should contain the id of the user.